# How to change checkbox after page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a checkbox that needs to update when the user changes the selected item in a GridView.  I can programmatically assign the database value to the checkbox on page load.  That works fine.  But I can't get the checkbox to refresh inside my GridView_SelectedIndexChanged function.

```
radioBtnDownPmtBrwd.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(lstBorrowerInfo.rbDwnPmtBrwd);
radioBtnEndorser.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(lstBorrowerInfo.rbEndorser);
```

The code above works great on Page_Load.  How do I trigger the screen to refresh when I change the checked/unchecked status from the code behind?

Comment: Are you using an `UpdatePanel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebind the `GridView` in the event handler code for the selected item changing. The `GridView` will only show what its `DataSource` says it has upon the most recent `DataBind` method call.

Putting this within an `UpdatePanel` will get rid of the blink refresh that occurs with standard ASP.NET WebForms postbacks, but `UpdatePanel`s are not a panacea.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood me.  The trigger to update the radio buttons is the gridview index change.  The radio buttons are outside the gridview itself.  I was using the index changed event to update the radio button as shown in the code above.  I'll try the update panel in the meantime.